Axis tilt, days, and a year
Hello I’m not really good at math. I was wondering what kind of effect a world with these attributes have: a 22 degree axis with 10 months, and and 307/306 days (7 months with 31 days, 3 months with 30 days and every leap year one would have a 29th day) also each day will have the typical 24 hours. I wanna know what kinds of effects this would have in seasons, how often would leap years be and other stuff that would be helpful. Also what would happen if the “main moon” has a lunar cycle every 15 days, how often might eclipses be? I’m kinda making a dark fantasy world for fun. It’s something I have been doing since i was super young.

Quite apart from there being too many questions there's not enough info to answer.  For example, leap years are when the period of travelling around the sun doesn't exactly align to the number of days - we don't know that, so leap years could be every second year or every 92nd year.  Re seasons - even if we had enough info on star type, atmosphere, geography, hydrology etc it's too broad - imagine trying to provide info about the seasons everywhere on Earth in less than book length.  Especially if it's a fantasy world then just make up what you like.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You are mixing up things.
Just to mention one, number and duration of the months of the calendar have no effects on the seasons: on our Earth, for example, having 2 months, 1 with 183 and one with 182 days, would not make the seasons any different. Calendar months are an artificial construct which humans try to superimpose on the substrate offered by nature. Since this superimposition is not perfect, humans have to do adjustments, like the leap year, because humans insist in having one year which lasts an entire number of days and not a fractional one.
Since your world is fictional, unless you are going to describe in detail the system giving the orbital parameters of the planet around its star, you can come up with anything that better suits your need. Nobody questioned the winter which was always coming in that famous work of fiction.
